# Как ускорить конвертацию svg в png через Inkscape

Tags: php, svg, png, inkscape

Сейчас конвертирую так: `inkscape -z -e test.png -w 100 -h 100 test.svg`, но это очень долго. Сохранять необходимо **без GUI**. Как можно ускорить сохранение?

Comment: Оно не только долго, но и не очень качественно. Тут я могу посоветовать разве что переходить на продукты Adobe.

Comment: @user7860670 мне качество и не нужно. Там чертежи.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо собрать команды, а потом скормить их `Inkscape`:

```
exec("inkscape --shell << \n$commands\nquit\n");
```